# How to boot to ClockworkMod recovery with Galaxy5 GT-i5500

Tags: clockworkmod-recovery, recovery-mode, boot, samsung-galaxy-5

I have ClockworkMod recovery installed on a phone (Samsung Galaxy5 GT-i5500, I have used it in the past to flash ROMs).

The phone is currently not booting, just shows the Samsung logo.

I want to get into the ClockworkMod recovery mode, by pressing some key combination. (Do not confuse with Samsung download mode: power-down+middle-button+power.)

How to get to CWM recovery mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to boot directly into CWM recovery by key combination. However one can boot into "download mode" (as described in question) and then (re)flash recovery with Odin, this will automatically reboot phone to CWM recovery